# SoapUI - set the JWT token as a global project parameter

Tags: soapui

I am new in SaopUI. I have created a project with resources. 
I need set some variables and use them for requests. For example I have my JWT token and the JWT token will be changed often (testing for different users and permissions = different JWT token) 
So, does exist way how I can set parameter globally for a project and use it as HEADER parameter for requests as "link" (on that parameter/value)?

Thank you!,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

You're probably interested in [Property Expantions](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/property-expansion.html)

> SoapUI provides a common syntax to dynamically insert ("expand") property values during processing. The syntax is as follows:
>
> ${[scope]propertyName[#xpath-expression]}
>
> where scope can be one of the following literal values:
>
> #Project# - references a Project property(Reference properties across a particular SoapUI project)
>
> #TestSuite# - references a TestSuite property in the containing TestSuite
>
> #TestCase# - references a TestCase property in the containing TestCase
>
> #MockService# - references a MockService property in the containing MockService
>
> #Global# - references a global property. Found in File>Preferences>Global Properties tab. Reference properties across all projects
>
> #System# - references a system property. Found in Help>System properties.
>
> #Env# - references an environment variable
>
> [TestStep name]# - references a TestStep property
>
> Many of the scopes will of course only work if they are available, i.e. you can not use the #MockService# scope within a TestCase script since there is no containing MockService to access.
>
> If no scope is specified, the property is resolved as follows:
>
> - Check the current context (for example the TestRunContext) for a property with the matching name
> - Check for a matching global property
> - Check for a matching system property

For example, you can create a groovy step to setup your variable:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

project = testRunner.getTestCase().testSuite.getProject();

testStep = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["YourApiRequestStep"]

def Response = testStep.getProperty("response").value;

def someFieldYouWantToSave = ""


if (Response == null) {
    log.error('No Response found.');
}
else {
    def jSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
    def json = jSlurper.parseText(Response);
    if (json.get("theFieldFromTheResponse") == null){
        log.error "TheFieldFromTheResponse not found in response. Please execute the teststep and try again"
    } else {
        someFieldYouWantToSave = json.get("theFieldFromTheResponse").toString()
        testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("someFieldYouWantToSave", someFieldYouWantToSave)
    }
}
```

You can then use the property in the request, like so:
${#Project#theFieldFromTheResponse}